# Select multiple photos in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How do i select multiple photos in WP8. I saw in demos, that its possible but was unable to find any SDK related to it in MSDN.

Currently I am selecting one image at once by using PhotoChooserTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the WP API let you select more than one photo at time. The "multiple selection" feature is intended just for selecting several pictures in the Pictures app and it's meant for quick share or deletion.

MSDN documentation is very clear about it, PhotoChooserTask is meant for selecting just one picture a time (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask(v=vs.105).aspx). I don't know any other way to access saved photos programmatically.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed with the WP Dev team that its not allowed for by 3rd Party developers.

Answer (score 2):

you could leverage this WP8 library:

https://multiphotochooser.codeplex.com/

It functions like a photochoosertask but it's capable of returning several images at a time.

[image: Sample:]