# Windows Phone 8.1 What share contract can I use to share multiple images

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently using this code to share one image , but I need to share more then one image at one time. Is there a different share contract? 
I see that the Windows Phone 8.1 can share multiple images from media gallery.

```
var shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask { FilePath = model.Path };
shareMediaTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) says:

The `share picker` allows your app to share a media item with one of the media-sharing apps that are installed on the phone.

Unfortunatly there are no other tasks available either to allow the sharing of several media items, the only option I can see is if there is any third-party app which has a [custom URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which can be launched to share multiple items.

Have a look over here [Select multiple photos in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874599)

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Windows Phone 8.1, you should use the [share contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871371.aspx), which allows for sharing multiple files.